# Editing catalog product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, frontend, fulltext

I would like to change the text of my product file.

to change the text "**19 pour inclut**" with "**tva inclue**"

I tried to find the file in `/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/`
but didn't find it

Pretty much like I tried to show on the pictures:

[image]

[image]

can somebody help?

Comment: you can start profiler and get template path hints so you can know from which file it is coming and you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable template path hints for find the right file for this follow the following steps:

1. Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration
2. Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration Scope ex:english
3. Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug. If you want both block and view template path hints, click yes on Template path hints (phtml files) and Add Block Names to Hints.
4. Refresh your frontend
   Now you can see the path of template file chage that text

[image]